# window.print() is not working in chrome 77 version

Tags: google-chrome

I am facing one issue since my chrome browser is updated to version 77.

Initially `window.print()` is working fine, but once I open a page where it includes embedded PDF using `<embed>` tag, `window.print()` stopped working. Using `Ctrl+P` shortcut it opens the print popup but when I execute `window.print()` in javascript it doesn't work.

I have executed `window.print()` command in console, it directly returns `undefined`.

There might be a some changes in Chrome 77 release as per this thread https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14107571?hl=en

Does any one have face this issue ? 
Please help.

Comment: I am also facing print issue in chrome 77 version. Using below code for print function
                
`pdfStamper.addJavaScript("this.print({bUI: true,bSilent:false,bShrinkToFit: true});");`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is related to Chrome settings issues, because turning off **chrome://flags/#mime-handler-view-in-cross-process-frame** fixing that issue.

[image: Chrome flags: MimeHandlerView in cross-process frame]

*For someone that did not know how to turn off that, please do this:*

- Open new tab on chrome, and type **chrome://flags/**
- You will have **Experiments** page opened.
- Then type: **Mime** on the search bar on that page.
- That will show you: **MimeHandlerView in cross-process frame**
- Change that value from: **Default** to: **Disabled**, then it will ask you to relaunch the chrome.

After the chrome restarted, the printing function will work fine.

Comment: This option isn't available now. Can you please let me know if it's renamed?

Answer (score -1):

I am facing some what similar issue - once the pdf file is rendered, by the chrome pdf viewer, the `window.print()` starts returning `undefined`.

More detailed description - A pdf file is rendered into the tab, user hits back and then print() stops working. It is important that all is executed in the same tab.

Comment: This does not help the user that asked the question. This should be a comment instead.

Comment: He is asking does anyone face the same issue - I am describing the way I did.

Comment: @ChoiLiu, have you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. My case is slightly different, as it is not auto print preview - as the user needs to click a button, which calls window.print method. It is worth mentioning that this issue was introduced with 77 release, the previous were OK.

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati, please check if this resolves the issue for you: disable chrome://flags/#mime-handler-view-in-cross-process-frame. This is not much of a fix, though.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var URL;

    $('#Print').click(function () {
        $('#embed').remove();
        URL= 'url';

        setTimeout(cPrint, 100);
    });
    function cPrint() {
        window.print();

        $('#div').append('<embed id="embed" src="' + URL + '" />');
    }

});
```

Comment: Would be nice of you to explain a bit your proposed answer so everybody can get it easily.